# Is it possible to compile swf files (Flash) from a linux command line?

Tags: flash, actionscript, compiler-construction, open-source, adobe

I'm trying to ascertain whether its possible to compile a set of .as / .swc files to a swf from a Linux (specificity Ubunto) command line.

Ideally it would be a free solution.

any suggestions would be fantastic.

Comment: The Flex SDK is free; Flash Builder, its IDE, is not.

Comment: so, I could use the Flex SDK via command line to this end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yep, use the mxmlc program that comes with the free flex sdk. this is essentially what flashdevelop is doing. you can get more info on it here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fcc.html

Comment: I worked this one out after icktoofay commented on my question, thanks for formalising the answer.