# Compile actionscript to swf file (*not* on an Intel platform computer)

Tags: linux, apache-flex, arm

Essentially, my question is the same as [Is it possible to compile swf files (Flash) from a linux command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480901/is-it-possible-to-compile-swf-files-flash-from-a-linux-command-line), except I need to perform the compilation on a machine with an ARM processor.  Is there a build of the Flex SDK that can run on ARM machines, or is there some other alternative approach that I can use?

Comment: The Flex compiler should work on Linux; and you can check the Apache flex list archives for information about that.  I have no idea if it'll work on ARM; you may have to compile it from the source and then try it yourself.

Comment: flex.apache.org does not seem to have any downloads that are appropriate for Linux at all; it only seems to support Windows and OSX.  Is Linux development going on elsewhere?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want me to say that I haven't already.  Check the Apache Flex list archives for information on getting the Flex Compiler to work on Linux.  Start here: http://markmail.org/search/?q=+list%3Aorg.apache.incubator.flex-dev+Linux#query:%20list%3Aorg.apache.incubator.flex-dev%20Linux+page:1+mid:req52bf52cpvs7ys+state:results You'll probably have to build it yourself, with an old version of the AIR SDK.

Comment: Right... and where do I get an AIR SDK for an ARM machine?

Comment: I would assume there is no AIR SDK specifically for ARM.  Have you tried to do what you're asking yet?

Comment: No, because I really don't understand how to do it.  The instructions seem to suggest that simply copying a Windows installation of the SDK to Linux and changing a few paths produces a working Linux installation, but there must be some operating-system specific code somewhere and this will need to be rebuilt to run on ARM.  I'm guessing that the system runs in some kind of virtual machine, which is how come it's portable between Windows and x86-Linux, but what is the virtual machine and where do I get a copy for ARM?  Is it AIR, or something else?

Comment: I think all the "OS Specific code" is in the runtimes; not in the build tools.  I think you need to try it and come back here if you have problems; as I don't think we're getting anywhere with this theoretical discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flex SDK runs in a Java virtual machine, and even in the Windows version includes shell scripts that are appropriate to launch it on any Unix-like system, so all that is required to use it is to install an appropriate JVM, copy the files from either the Windows or MacOS X distribution of Flex, and change the paths in the configuration files to something appropriate.

There are also alternatives that could be compiled to run as native code (which may be more appropriate for memory-constrained devices like many embedded targets), although these are generally less capable than the official Flex SDK.  I looked at "[libming](http://www.libming.org)" which has an associated actionscript compiler, but this only supports actionscript 2 (I needed actionscript 3).  [SWFTools](http://swftools.org/) has a compiler that supports actionscript 3, but it does not appear to be complete, unfortunately, and lacked support for embedding objects which I required.  The same package, however, also has a number of other utilities, including one that can read in a source swf, and rewrite it with an embedded object replaced by the contents of an external file.  As this is all I actually needed to do, I determined that doing it this way is more efficient than recompiling the entire actionscript project each time I need a new file.